# Google chrome crashing while uploading larger files using (event.target as FileReader).result . (File size greater than 80mb)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blob, filereader, onload

I am trying to pass my file from browser to server via the formData object like below. 
But the code crashs the browser(google chrome) when i upload larger file ( > 80mb).

```
const formData: IUploadFileBlobModel = {
                    fileName: file.fileName,
                    description: file.description,
                    mimeType: file.file.type,
                    fileBlob: (event.target as FileReader).result
                };
```

/*can we use any other methods instead of   (event.target as FileReader).result */

Comment: is there any web server in the middle (apache , Nginx)?

Comment: Yes, we using IIS server.

Comment: What is the point of the FileReader here? `file.file` is a File, which means it's a Blob and that [can be sent through a Network request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) as is or wrapped inside a FormData. No need to *read* it.

Comment: @Kaiido when sending it as a file, the browser automatically adds the filename to the request, while a blob doesn't do this. This is probably not an issue for the OP however

Comment: @Kaiido,i think  the statement (event.target as FileReader).result is  actually failing. This point crashing the browser, i think.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to try to check large files confiig for IIS at first:

```
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

More info: [IIS](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm)